# panorama photos on iPhone 6 are too narrow

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

I'm trying to take panorama photos with the camera of the iPhone 6s and the resulting files are shorter than what I am seeing when I capture.

The photo I've attached (scaled down because upload-limit) should have an angle of estimated 160 degrees instead of maybe 110 degrees. Basically, the image saved is shorter than the preview indicates on the phone.

But when I open the image in the Mac photo-app it shows only the first part. So to say: The beginning of the desired panorama. The rest (further to the left of what is shown) is somehow gone.

I'm doing it exactly the way it is explained in several youtube-videos: Keeping the arrow as exact as possible over the line while turning the device.

**Am I doing something wrong or what troubleshooting approaches work to get a wider panorama photo?**

[image]

Comment: I've never stopped a pano - might have to experiment. I'm assuming if you power off the iPhone and restart it, you get the same results? I also wonder what happens if you just let the pano capture everything and keep turning the phone rather than tap to end.

Comment: I'm goanna try this out. Restart the phone currently. I report back.

Comment: I have managed to get a panorama shot the first time. But in portrait mode. It seem to be important to move really slow. But still not sure what it significant for getting a proper panorama shot reliable.

Comment: It's definitely easier to archive a panorama shot with holding the device vertical (Portrait mode) then holding it horizontal.

Comment: What I can say so far: It's important to follow the direction of the arrow and to move slow.

Comment: Nice. Please put up your answer. I find in low light, it it s helpful to place the camera on a book or other heavy object. The mass + inertia slows down the panning and engaged larger muscle groups which results in better shots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have figured out myself by trying:

1. Hold the iPhone vertical (Portrait mode).
2. Start the picture-taking by pressing the software button.
3. Turn the phone in the direction in which the arrow points. 
   **Move the phone rather slow but steadily.**

Keep the tip of the arrow as close on the line as possible.

You are shown some kind of thumbnail image. That is the panorama view which you got already recorded. If the whole thing works you can see how the panorama view grows.

By the way: 
You can change the direction of the arrow before you start the picture-taking by tipping on the arrow.

4. Finalise the picture-taking by pressing the software button again.